# How to reduce granularity using analytics?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, analytics

My detail records are too granular and I'd like to group my descriptions into varieties.
How can I use Oracle analytic functions to do this? I prefer to use analytic tools because this is a snippet of a much larger query and some of its columns call analytic functions. I'd like to add just another column to this existing query.

[My Attempt on Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2a20/11)

```
   select lumber_vend,
     case lumber_code
          when 'H1' then 'HARDWOOD'
          when 'O1' then 'OAK' 
          when 'O2' then 'OAK'
          when 'P1' then 'PINE'
          when 'P2' then 'PINE'
          when 'P3' then 'PINE'
    else 'OTHER'
    end  as variety,
          rank() over (partition by lumber_code,
                                    lumber_vend,
                               case lumber_code
                               when 'H1' then '1'
                               when 'O1' then '2' 
                               when 'O2' then '2'
                               when 'P1' then '3'
                               when 'P2' then '3'
                               when 'P3' then '3'
                               else 'OTHER'
                               end                                         
                        order by lumber_desc) as ranking                                 
   from lumber_detail
```

**Desired Results**

```
AAA HARDWOOD
AAA PINE
AAA OAK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking for.  After all, `group by` makes the most sense to get the output you want.  But, if you want to enumerate the rows for each vendor and variety, then use `row_number()` instead of `rank()` and use a better `order by` term:

```
select lumber_vend,
       (case lumber_code
           when 'H1' then 'HARDWOOD'
           when 'O1' then 'OAK' 
           when 'O2' then 'OAK'
           when 'P1' then 'PINE'
           when 'P2' then 'PINE'
           when 'P3' then 'PINE'
           else 'OTHER'
        end)  as variety,
       row_number() over (partition by lumber_vend,
                            (case lumber_code
                                      when 'H1' then '1'
                                 when 'O1' then '2' 
                                 when 'O2' then '2'
                                 when 'P1' then '3'
                                 when 'P2' then '3'
                                 when 'P3' then '3'
                                 else 'OTHER'
                             end)
                           order by lumber_vend
                    ) as ranking                                 
from lumber_detail;
```

This will allow you to have `where ranking = 1` to select one row from each group.

Comment: Gordon, you understood well. I wanted to avoid `group by` if possible. This is exactly what I wanted. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2a20/28. Thanks.